# PHP: Куки устанавливаются со второго раза.

Tags: php, cookie

В общем, ситуация следующая:

Стоит авторизация через ВК, если авторизоваться - куки не ставятся, а если повторить операцию - всё работает с тем же кодом. Не в первый раз такое - раньше ситуация как-то сама собой решалась, а теперь не знаю что делать.

Может кто-то сталкивался?
**UPD:**

```
  if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
    session_start();
    $s = file_get_contents('Запрос данных');
    $user = json_decode($s, true);

    $id = $user['identity'];
    $name = $user['first_name'];
    $lastname = $user['last_name'];

    $secondPastOfYear = 15778463;

    // Ставим куки
    SetCookie('id', $id, time() + $secondPastOfYear, "/");
    SetCookie('name', $name, time() + $secondPastOfYear, "/");
    SetCookie('lastname', $lastname, time() + $secondPastOfYear, "/");
  }
```

Comment: А что будет если авторизоваться, а потом – F5? Есть предположение, что сработает. Если так — то проверить порядок посыла (не определения значения) куки и проверки. Кто вообще записывает куки: страница или PHP-скрипт?

Comment: Работает. Данные в POST опять приходят, и на второй раз срабатывает.
Стоит проверка - если существует глобальный массив POST - то пишем куки из него. Всё, больше ничего особого. Код добавлю в вопрос.

Comment: Ну вот... Опять ситуация ушла сама собой. Всё опять работает нормально непонятно почему :) Так что у кого появится подобное - просто ждите (на самом деле нет) :)